# JQuery RateIt plugin bug - Stars not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer

I am having that problem that my Jquery RateIt stars does not appear in IE. I have tested demos on the website for the RateIt plugin. And the stars works fine on the RateIt website.

My website: http://www.vinderhimlen.dk

The Rateit plugin website: http://rateit.codeplex.com

IE 9:

[image]

Firefox 4: [image]

Comment: It seems to work on IE 8

Comment: Seems to work fine under Fx4 too.

Comment: I have updated the post with the IE 9 bug

Comment: Interesting. Let me check with SuperPreview.

Comment: Yeah, this only seems to affect IE9. A bit offtopic but the design seems to spaz out a bit under IE7.

Comment: Interesting, the only error that happens on IE9 but not on Fx4 is that document.getElementsByTagName doesn't exist, but that only seems to freak jquery.js out

Comment: Have you tried updating to jQuery 1.6.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess upgrading to jQuery 1.6.1 should fix this issue:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8052

Also you have jQuery referenced twice in your document:

First version 1.5.1:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and a few lines later (version 1.5):

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1304726399" type="text/javascript"></script>
```